discord.py のコマンドを他のbotが送信しても受け付けられるようにしたい
現在私はカメラモジュールを搭載したRaspberryPi 3で、discordから特定のコマンド(!logged)を受信した際に写真を撮影、チャンネルに撮影した画像を送信するプログラムを搭載しようとしています。
プログラムは一度形になり、一般のアカウントがコマンドを入力した際は正常に作動するようになりました。
次に、google spreadsheetからのwebhookが同じコマンドを送信した際にも同じく作動してほしいと思いRaspberry Pi側にプログラムを追加しました。しかし、webhook含め他のbotがコマンドを送信した際には一切反応を見せませんでした。
webhook側に異常があるのかもと考え、Raspberry Piに絡まない他のbotに似たプログラムを搭載して動かした際には正常に作動しました。
追加で必要な情報があれば是非教えて下さい。
何がおかしいのかご教授お願い致します。
#以下webhookのプログラム(js)

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  

  // Webhook URL
  var webhookUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/-----';
  
  // Discordに送信するメッセージ
  var message = {
    content: 'login'
  };
  
  // メッセージを送信
  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(message)
  };
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhookUrl, options);
}


#以下Raspberry Pi内のプログラム(py)

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import picamera
import asyncio

CHANNEL_ID = ----

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')
    
    
async def send_image():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (1024,768)
        camera.capture('image.jpg')
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(file=discord.File('image.jpg'))
    
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        return
    await bot.prossess_commands(message)
    
@bot.command()
async def logged (message):
        await send_image()
        await message.send('image sended')
    
bot.run('----')


Raspberry Pi内のプログラムの中にあるasync def on_message(message):のコードの前に@bot.eventが必要です。そうでないとdiscord.pyがこのコードに気づかず、反応を見せないのです。
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message) # タイプミス: prossess_commands -> process_commands

さらに、if文の中のコードと外にあるコードが同じなので修正したほうが良いでしょう。
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)

